# How could you pass user input through a method with varargs (variable arguments) in Java?

Tags: java, methods, variadic-functions, subroutine

I'm doing a project for school where we have to create multiple different subroutines. I have a general idea for how to pass user-inputted values through subroutines, but I'm not sure how to do so for subroutines that have a variable number of arguments.

For reference, here's the code for the subroutine I made.

```
 public static double averageOf (double ...dataset)
          {

              double numbersInDataset = dataset.length;
              //Add the numbers together
              double total = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i<=numbersInDataset; i = i+1)
              {
                  total = total + dataset[i];
              }
              //Calculate the average
              double average = total / numbersInDataset;
              //Return the average
              return average;
```

Given how this subroutine is set up, how could I pass user input through it?

Comment: `double ...dataset == double[] dataset`

Comment: Don't use `<=` when looping from `0` to `dataset.length`.

Comment: If you are reading the input from user input or from a file, varagrs are probably not going to help.  You'll likely read the data into an array, and pass the array to your method.